# Getting background locations when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, maps, core-location

This is my simple current code to get location updates:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

     var locationManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {

        print("in here")
        if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
            print("App in Foreground")

        } else {

            let Device = UIDevice.currentDevice()
            let iosVersion = Double(Device.systemVersion) ?? 0

            let iOS9 = iosVersion >= 9
            if iOS9{
                // This part gives me error which i think is needed to allow background updates in ios9?
                //locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
                //locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO;
            }
            //let iOS7 = iosVersion >= 7 && iosVersion < 8
            print("App is backgrounded. New location is %@", newLocation)
        }
    }


}
```

I have added NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription to my plist file and made so background locations updates are possible in the app so no worries there.

This code works fine when running in the simulator for both foreground and background. Then I wanted to try it on my device and as soon as I background the app it does not update any locations. I have read in several places that for iOS 9 you need to add this code:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
```

I am trying to put it in my code in swift but I get this error message:

```
Cannot assign value of type 'ObjCBool' to type 'Bool'
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the Objective-C boolean literal `YES`, which imports into Swift as type `ObjCBool`. Just switch to using the Swift boolean literal `true` and you should be good to go.

Comment: Tried that aswell before posting it. I get this error then: Use of unresolved identifier 'TRUE'

Comment: lol mybad. i was using capital letters. i just thought wait a minute what if he litteraly means low capitals. Thank you :P

Comment: I am still not able to get the locations when the app is in the background mode. I have added UIBackgroundmodes to "location" and also called this    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9) {
        _locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = YES;
    }
before calling startUpdatingLocation but still the locationManager delegate method "didUpdateToLocation:" doesnt fire when the app is in background. Please help if you have found out with this solution.